# Stop different Manipulate Panels from triggering each other

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This should be a simple question, but I have given up on it after a while now. 
I have different input lines which I have evaluated in a single notebook. Two of these have manipulate statements:

The first one

```
Manipulate[{  Some Plot Func }, {{\[Omega]0, 3}, 0, 3}, {{\[Tau], 5}, -1, 20}]
```

The second One:

```
Manipulate[{  Some Plot Func }, {Twave, 1, 10}, {{Tenv, 10}, 0, 100}, TrackedSymbols :> True]
```

When I change parameters in the second one, i can see the first one evaluating as well.

I have tried specifying with TrackedSymbols to disentangle the two, but this does not succeed. I hope someone can point me to the obvious solution. It is slowing down evaluation a lot.

Thank you!

Comment: It would help to know what `Some Plot Func` is. Are you perhaps updating global parameters in one of the `Manipulate`s that appears in the other one as well? Also, there is a [new site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) for Mathematica related questions on stackexchange where you might get a better response.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

End each of your manipulates with a semicolon.
Create a third "master" manipulate which does not end with a semicolon.
Within the master manipulate, use a TabView. With each pane of the tab, run one of your manipulates by calling it like a function. It is convenient to create a list of your manipulates and pick the one to execute with a "tab index" of sorts.

I've gotten this to work well with several manipulates, rules for moving between them via the tabs, and so forth. It's proven to be a useful approach for notebook applications,as the complexity of one giant manipulate gets out of hand.